# Trash config for hdfs not working

Tags: hdfs, webhdfs

After adding following config in core-site.xml for hdfs, it does not create `/user/X/.Trash` folder when using webhdfs delete API.

```
<property>
    <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
    <value>10080</value> 
    </property>
<property>
    <name>fs.trash.checkpoint.interval</name>
    <value>1440</value>
</property>
```

Expectation is that, all the deleted files must be in `.Trash` folder for the trash interval. However it works when using hadoop command (`hadoop fs -rm /test/1`). Does anyone has any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

As specified [here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cm_mc_config_trash.html)

> The trash feature works by default only for files and directories deleted using the Hadoop shell. Files or directories deleted programmatically using other interfaces (WebHDFS or the Java APIs, for example) are not moved to trash, even if trash is enabled, unless the program has implemented a call to the trash functionality. (Hue, for example, implements trash as of CDH 4.4.)